# Fastest way to guess a number only knowing if it is higher or lower than the previous guess?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem where I would have to guess a number between 1 and 2 * 10^9, only knowing if it is higher or lower than my previous guess.

Right now I have a code that works for all the cases but it exceeds the guess limit which is only 31.

```
status = ""
high = 2000000000
low = 1
num = low
print num
while 1:
    status= raw_input()
    if status== "OK":
        break
    elif status == "Higher":
        low = num
    elif status == "Lower":
        high = num
    num = int((high+low)/2)
    print num
```

What I am doing is starting with the lowest number as my first guess, and reset the low and the high based on the response.

Can you help me find a faster way?

Comment: Seems like you actually start with `low`, not the middle number.

Comment: 2E9 < 2^31, so you should be able to get to the answer in 31 guesses or less.

Comment: You need to **start** with the appropriate guess formula -- `(high+low)//2` is best, btw -- by starting with `1` you're wasting almost one full bit of information as you'll get the "Higher" response the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your starting position to the middle of the range:

```
num = low
```

Should be:

```
num = int((low + high) / 2)
```

This is the fastest possible way, and it's called [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

You're using the best possible algorithm. Except (edit to account for Jonathan's comment):  Your initial guess is as bad as possible.  Take the initial guess to be int((low+high)/2).  This will drop the number of times through the cycle by 1.

What you're doing is a binary search.  If the number you're trying to guess really is random, then you can't do better.

Think of what would happen **if you didn't guess the midpoint** each time.  When your guess has more values on one side than the other, the number you're trying to find is more likely to be on the side with more values.  So most of the time you eliminate fewer than half of the values.  So **more often than not** you would **have a harder problem** to solve.  If you take the midpoint each time, then you cut the number of values in half each time.  If you take some other value then on average you have more than half of them left.

So the only change I would suggest is to start with

```
num = int((high+low)/2)
```

It's worth considering using

```
(high+low)//2
```

instead of having the call to `int`.  This returns an integer regardless of whether you're using python 2 or 3:  `(high+low)/2` would have different behavior in the two versions of python.

Comment: Not quite: the initial guess is sub-optimal.

Comment: I had seen "with the middle number as my first guess" in the post and hadn't checked the code carefully.